# How to get the data from an arraylist and display that data in Recyclerview Adapter?

Tags: android

How to get the data from an arraylist and display that data in Recyclerview Adapter?

The code:

```
Call<List<Get_Question_Response>> newCall = apiInterface.getQuestions(GID);
   newCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Get_Question_Response>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse (Call < List < Get_Question_Response >> call, Response < List < Get_Question_Response >> response) {
        List<Get_Question_Response> result2s = response.body();
        show_questions_adapter = new ShowAdapter(getApplicationContext(), result2s);
        show_recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(pos);
        show_recyclerView.setAdapter(show_questions_adapter);
        show_questions_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure (Call < List < Get_Question_Response >> call, Throwable t){
    Log.d("Response", "onFailure: " + t);
}
});
```

Comment: Don't just post code, explain your problem, include error messages and show us how you tried to solve it.

Comment: Please provide proper information.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating your adapter instance in the onResponse method. What I like to do is to create it in the onCreate method with an empty list:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
    show_questions_adapter = new ShowAdapter(getApplicationContext(),new ArrayList()); 
    show_recyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(pos); 
    show_recyclerView.setAdapter(show_questions_adapter); 
...
}
```

and then have an addItems method in the adapter:

```
public void addItems(List<String> items){
    this.result2s.clear();
    this.result2s.addAll(items);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
Call<List<Get_Question_Response>> newCall = apiInterface.getQuestions(GID);
newCall.enqueue(new Callback>() { @Override public void onResponse(Call> call, 
Response> response) { 
    List result2s = response.body(); 
    show_questions_adapter.addItems(result2s);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Get_Question_Response>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Response", "onFailure: " + t);
        }
    });
```